# Issue Setting up IIS URL Rewrite Rule --> ARR

Tags: iis

Hey everyone it's been a while since I've messed with IIS and I've been asked to implement some changes. (I'm more of a GIS guys then a web admin)

We have a web server humming along at https://my.work.com/

A solution just got deployed to 192.168.1.1:1234/iv

I've verified that the web server can talk to the application server over the correct port and I have a server farm set up in IIS. Our team and clients need to be able to access the solution at https://my.work.com/iv

I'm hitting a wall in setting up my URL rewrite correctly since I'm not 100% sure what the incoming pattern and outgoing path should be. Any help would be appreciated.

[IIS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mPa3.jpg)

Comment: 1. Learn regular expressions so that you can write the correct patterns. 2. Use ARR to build a reverse proxy is more than enough, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing so you don't need the web farm part.

Comment: I would like to confirm with you if your web page can be accessed normally through `https://my.work.com:1234/iv`? And you want to be able to access the page through `https://my.work.com/iv` without port `1234`.